# Dublicate rows for translator in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

The site is translated into different by taking text from the table. Then the program gets into the database, translates and fills in the table, where there is an empty translation. The program takes only the text where there is no translation. In order to be translated into all languages you need to copy the string with an empty translation in different languages and then the program will translate.

In MYSQL table appers not translated rows for translator

```
select text,`from`,`to` from Translation where tran=''
```

[image: MySQL Result]

I need prepare rows in other languages to same table

Something like this

```
insert into Translation (text,`from`,`to`)
select text, `from`, `to`
from Translation
where `to` not in ('en','zh','ar','th')
  and `to` != `from`
  and tran = ''
```

How to do it?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your expected output. Its not clear what your issue is.

Comment: There is not enough detail in this question to on. It sounds like you are trying to create a table of word translations from/to English, Chinese, Arabic, Thai. Where "text" is the word in the original language, "from" is the original language, "to" is the target language, and "tran" is the word translated into the target language? What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to populated this table for missing values, or just trying to find your missing values? "to != from" looks like excluding cognates, is that all you want?

Comment: Appropriate questions for Stack Overflow are usually - "I have this input, need to perform this specific operation(s) to get this output" or are targeted to specific technical error. Open ended questions like "how do I go about this project" are not usually well suited to this forum.

Comment: The site is translated into different by taking text from the table. If there is a new text without translation in the table you need to duplicate it in other languages. Then the program gets into the database, translates and fills in the table, where there is an empty translation. The program takes only the text where there is no translation. In order to be translated into all languages you need to copy the string with an empty translation in different languages and then the program will translate.

Comment: Of course you want the language of the phrase and the translation not to be the same, so 'from' != 'to'

Comment: Yes , "text" is the word in the original language, "from" is the original language, "to" is the target language, and "tran" is the word translated into the target language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something to fiddle around with. It's completely untested. Just to give the general idea for a pattern to impute missing values, or create placeholder records, from a seed set.

```
WITH 
  all_language_codes as
  ( select distinct
           `from`
      from translations
  ),
  words_which_have_no_translation_in_any_language as
  ( select text,
           `from`
      from translations t1
     where not exists
             ( select 1
                 from translations t2
                where t1.text = t2.text
                  and coalesce(trim(t2.tran),'') <> ''
             )
  )
select wwt.text,
       wwt.from,
       alc.from as to,
       '' as tran
  from words_which_have_no_translation_in_any_language wwt
 cross
  join all_language_codes alc
 where wwt.`from` <> alc.`from`
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed. I just created additional tables and checked the result

Comment: result: insert into Translation (text,`from`,`to`) select t.text,
       t.`from`, l.lang as `to`  from Translation t
 cross join Languages l where t.`from` <> l.`lang` and t.tran = ''